# classification of machine learning optimization algorithms

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

What are the various categories of machine learning optimization algorithms?
At some place its mentioned that Optimization Algorithm falls under 2 major categories -

```
    First Order Optimization Algorithms and second order Optimization Algorithms
```

Some also classify it majorly as-

```
    Convex Optimization and Non-Convex Optimization
```

Whereas others also view it as-

```
    Constrained and Unconstrained Optimization
```

After all these classifications I cant seem to understand what falls under what category and please do point me towards any classification tree for the same if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a tree out of the categories you provided.

```
First Order Optimization Algorithms and second order Optimization Algorithms
```

Distinguishes algorithms by whether they use first-order derivatives exclusively in the optimization method or not. That is a characteristic of the algorithm itself.

```
Convex Optimization and Non-Convex Optimization
```

Distinguishes if the goal of the optimization is to find the minimum of a convex  or non-convex function. So that is a characteristic of the problem function being optimized. Generally speaking, optimizing a convex function is easier than a non-convex one.

```
Constrained and Unconstrained Optimization
```

Just tells you if there are any constraints in the parameters of the function you try to optimize. That is a characteristic of the problem you try to solve. Generally speaking, a constrained problem is easier to solve than an unconstrained one.

These things are not mutually exclusive. For example, you could try to minimize a non-convex function without constraints with a first order optimization algorithm. You could also look at constrained non-convex functions and try to minimize it with a second-order algorithm.